# PGAdmin4 on ECS Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, pgadmin-4, aws-fargate

I am trying to run PGAdmin4 as a docker container on AWS Fargate but for some reason the container is exiting.  Cloudwatch logs were not so helpful either.

Here is my Task definiton and Service. Indentation may not be accurate after copying it here.

```
Task:
Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
Properties:
  Family: pgadmin
  Cpu: 2048
  Memory: 4096
  NetworkMode: awsvpc
  RequiresCompatibilities:
    - FARGATE
  ExecutionRoleArn: !Ref ECSTaskExecutionRole
  ContainerDefinitions:
    - Name: pgadmin
      Image: dpage/pgadmin4 # From dockerhub
      Cpu: 2048
      Memory: 4096
      PortMappings:
        - ContainerPort: 80
          Protocol: tcp
      LogConfiguration:
        LogDriver: awslogs
        Options:
          awslogs-group: pgadmin
          awslogs-region: !Ref AWS::Region
          awslogs-stream-prefix: pgadmin
      Environment:          
        - Name: PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL
          Value: s-polimetla@s-polimetla.de
        - Name: PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD
          Value: test1234

Service:
Type: AWS::ECS::Service
DependsOn: ListenerRule
Properties:
  ServiceName: pgadmin-service
  TaskDefinition: !Ref Task
  Cluster: !Ref ECSCluster
  LaunchType: FARGATE
  DesiredCount: 1
  DeploymentConfiguration:
    MaximumPercent: 200
    MinimumHealthyPercent: 100
  NetworkConfiguration:
    AwsvpcConfiguration:
      AssignPublicIp: ENABLED
      Subnets:
        - Fn::ImportValue:
            !Sub ${NetworkStackName}-subnet1
        - Fn::ImportValue:
            !Sub ${NetworkStackName}-subnet2
      SecurityGroups:
        - Fn::ImportValue:
            !Sub ${NetworkStackName}-container-SG
  LoadBalancers:
    - ContainerName: pgadmin
      ContainerPort: 80
      TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup
```

My cloudwatch logs show the following

[image]

[image]

You can find the complete template [here](https://github.com/S-Polimetla/cloud-formation-templates/blob/master/containers/pgadmin.yaml).  Please feel free to correct it if you find anything wrong with it.

I cannot figure out what went wrong from the logs. Any pointers here?

Comment: You can go to ECS console, and check for stopped tasks. When you expand them, you should get more details.

Comment: Are you attaching with Load Balancer? If so, try verifying the health check URL. I think pgadmin has `/misc/ping` as a health check URL. 
Also, note that Fargate storage is ephemeral.

Comment: @Haran I just found that the property HealthCheck is no longer there for LoadBalancingV2 for cloudformation.  It was there for previous version

Comment: The health check command will be provided in `AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup`-HealthCheckPath. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-targetgroup.html#cfn-elasticloadbalancingv2-targetgroup-healthcheckpath

Comment: @Haran your comment should be the answer!