# Healthcheck request timed out when running pgadminin ecs

Tags: amazon-ecs, pgadmin

I'm running pgadmin in AWS ECS behind ALB.

Previously, I was using docker image `dpage/pgadmin4:4.30` and health check path was configured to `/misc/ping` and everything worked just fine.

Now, I've decided to update to `dpage/pgadmin4:6` (I also tried `5.7`). With this version healthcheck fails and I get `request timed out` messages in ECS service events.

I've tried to run docker containers of versions 4.30 and 6 on my local machine and curl  `/misc/ping` endpoint. I got identical replies.

AWS ECS Container logs are also very similar.

This is from v 4.30:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   timestamp   |                                                                        message                                                                         |
|---------------|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1634472755491 | NOTE: Configuring authentication for SERVER mode.                                                                                                      |
| 1634472760594 | [2021-10-17 12:12:40 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0                                                                                        |
| 1634472760594 | [2021-10-17 12:12:40 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://[::]:80 (1)                                                                                |
| 1634472760594 | [2021-10-17 12:12:40 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: threads                                                                                           |
| 1634472760595 | /usr/local/lib/python3.9/os.py:1023: RuntimeWarning: line buffering (buffering=1) isn't supported in binary mode, the default buffer size will be used |
| 1634472760595 |   return io.open(fd, *args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                  |
| 1634472760596 | [2021-10-17 12:12:40 +0000] [87] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 87                                                                                    |
| 1634472799837 | ::ffff:10.0.75.205 - - [17/Oct/2021:12:13:19 +0000] "GET /misc/ping HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"                                        |
| 1634472799838 | ::ffff:10.0.46.82 - - [17/Oct/2021:12:13:19 +0000] "GET /misc/ping HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"                                         |
| 1634472825983 | ::ffff:10.0.75.205 - - [17/Oct/2021:12:13:45 +0000] "GET /misc/ping HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"                                        |
| 1634472825990 | ::ffff:10.0.46.82 - - [17/Oct/2021:12:13:45 +0000] "GET /misc/ping HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"                                         |
| 1634472855984 | ::ffff:10.0.75.205 - - [17/Oct/2021:12:14:15 +0000] "GET /misc/ping HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"                                        |
| 1634472855995 | ::ffff:10.0.46.82 - - [17/Oct/2021:12:14:15 +0000] "GET /misc/ping HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"                                         |
| 1634472885994 | ::ffff:10.0.75.205 - - [17/Oct/2021:12:14:45 +0000] "GET /misc/ping HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"                                        |
| 1634472886001 | ::ffff:10.0.46.82 - - [17/Oct/2021:12:14:46 +0000] "GET /misc/ping HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"                                         |
| 1634472916003 | ::ffff:10.0.75.205 - - [17/Oct/2021:12:15:16 +0000] "GET /misc/ping HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"                                        |
| 1634472916014 | ::ffff:10.0.46.82 - - [17/Oct/2021:12:15:16 +0000] "GET /misc/ping HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"                                         |
| 1634472946010 | ::ffff:10.0.46.82 - - [17/Oct/2021:12:15:46 +0000] "GET /misc/ping HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"                                         |
| 1634472946016 | ::ffff:10.0.75.205 - - [17/Oct/2021:12:15:46 +0000] "GET /misc/ping HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"                                        |
| 1634472976016 | ::ffff:10.0.46.82 - - [17/Oct/2021:12:16:16 +0000] "GET /misc/ping HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"                                         |
| 1634472976023 | ::ffff:10.0.75.205 - - [17/Oct/2021:12:16:16 +0000] "GET /misc/ping HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"                                        |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and this is from v6

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   timestamp   |                                                     message                                                     |
|---------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1634473202325 | NOTE: Configuring authentication for SERVER mode.                                                               |
| 1634473226234 | [2021-10-17 12:20:26 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0                                                 |
| 1634473226235 | [2021-10-17 12:20:26 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://[::]:80 (1)                                         |
| 1634473226235 | [2021-10-17 12:20:26 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: gthread                                                    |
| 1634473226237 | [2021-10-17 12:20:26 +0000] [88] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 88                                             |
| 1634473272628 | ::ffff:10.0.75.205 - - [17/Oct/2021:12:21:12 +0000] "GET /misc/ping HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" |
| 1634473280062 | ::ffff:10.0.75.205 - - [17/Oct/2021:12:21:20 +0000] "GET /misc/ping HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" |
| 1634473280065 | ::ffff:10.0.46.82 - - [17/Oct/2021:12:21:20 +0000] "GET /misc/ping HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"  |
| 1634473310067 | ::ffff:10.0.75.205 - - [17/Oct/2021:12:21:50 +0000] "GET /misc/ping HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" |
| 1634473310069 | ::ffff:10.0.46.82 - - [17/Oct/2021:12:21:50 +0000] "GET /misc/ping HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"  |
| 1634473340068 | ::ffff:10.0.75.205 - - [17/Oct/2021:12:22:20 +0000] "GET /misc/ping HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" |
| 1634473340072 | ::ffff:10.0.46.82 - - [17/Oct/2021:12:22:20 +0000] "GET /misc/ping HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"  |
| 1634473364822 | [2021-10-17 12:22:44 +0000] [1] [INFO] Handling signal: term                                                    |
| 1634473365098 | [2021-10-17 12:22:45 +0000] [88] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 88)                                                |
| 1634473366827 | [2021-10-17 12:22:46 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master                                                    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Both seem to receive healthcheck request and reply with 200. However v6 version gets killed.

Has anyone been able to configure healthcheck for `dpage/pgadmin4:6`?

Comment: Did you have any answer? I have the same problem here. I think it is the same of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63222223/pgadmin4-on-ecs-fargate

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the pgAdmin4.log in /.pgadmin directory ?

Comment: Hi Aditya! Does the pgAdmin4.log detail why healthchecks time out, or do you think it's info that might help answer the question (But won't, by itself, provide an answer)?  If the latter, you might want to add this as a comment on the original question, rather then an independent answer.

Comment: That's the application log. If an app is crashing, first thing to do is check the logs. That's the reason I was asking if he has checked the log file.

Answer (score 0):

I had also similar issues while deploying on ecs and found out it requires larger compute and memory resources than the defaults, i.e 1vCpu and 2Gb memory

I am using the following configs with cdk

```json
memoryLimitMiB: 2048,
cpu: 1024,
```